# Questions regarding Aiyadigal Kadavarkon Nayanar

Tags: shiva, nayanar

What are the main contributions of Aiyadigal Kadavarkon Nayanar to Shaivism and under which number he falls out of 63? What are the main hymns he composed?

Comment: Periya Puranam gives info about Nayanars and great verses they composed. Shaivam.org has [Periya Puranam](http://shaivam.org/english/sen_th12.htm).

Answer (score 2):

[Aiyadigal Kadavarkon Nayanar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aiyadigal_Kadavarkon_Nayanar), counted as 46th among 63 Nayanars, composed **Kshetra Thiruvenba.** Kshetram means place, area. To be precise, it was composed by him when he visited different sacred places where temples of Shiva were situated. This poem said to be very big, but among them only 24 are surviving. Using this 24, Shekkizhar composed his life history in Periya Puranam. This Kshetra Thiruvenba is a part of 11th [Thirumurai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tirumurai) among other hymns sung by Karaikal Ammaiyar, Nambiyandar Nambi, etc.